# replace string from a certain character javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have created a custom @mention system for my app, my only problem is ill start typing `@...` and then Ill select the user I want to mention and what happens is that the name of the selected user is just added onto the end of the `textarea` so this works If I only typed in `@` but if I typed in `@ja` and then selected `jason smith` it would now say `@jaJason Smith` How Can I remove any text typed after the @ and then add on my string. FYI this is done in a `textarea`

so my current function looks like this..

```
addMention(user: any): void {
  const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
  const mentionSelect = <HTMLElement>document.querySelector('.mention-container');
  const value = textarea.value; // Store the value
  textarea.value = `${textarea.value}${user.value}`; // Current Value
  mentionSelect.style.display = 'none'; // Hide the mention list
  this.message = textarea.value; // Make sure the new textarea value is stored in message
  textarea.focus(); // refocus
  textarea.value = ''; // clear
  textarea.value = value; // add the value back in
}
```

so whats happening is Im just updating the value of the textarea by adding on the username

**EDIT**

It has been brought to my attention this is not the best way to do it since if a user moves the cursor to the middle and types @ the name will be added to the end of the string and not the @ so my question is how can I replace the string after the @ but be able to do it anywhere in the textarea??

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How do you go about grabbing the `@ja` in the first place? You're looking at a couple issues. One, you don't remove the characters you used to grab the name before appending and two, you only append to the end of the string. What if they went back and added a mention in the middle?

Comment: @NickAbbott thats a good point, do you have a better solution??

Comment: @SmokeyDawson $('#textarea').prop("selectionStart"); gives you the position of the cursor. Then all you need to do is to find the most recent `@` before this position.

Comment: @user3003238 without jquery?

Comment: @SmokeyDawson Simply `textarea.selectionStart` https://jsfiddle.net/7n41o5kq/3/

Comment: @user3003238 how do I find the most recent @ symbol from the selection start??

Comment: @SmokeyDawson find all index of '@xx' ('@ja' in your case), choose argmin(selectionStart - index) where selectionStart >= index

Comment: @user3003238 could you please post your answer??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simplified version of a solution. I don't have your setup to test this out and there is certainly a cleaner way to do it but this should give you an idea of where to go.

```
addMention(user: { value: string }): void {
  const textArea = document.querySelector('textarea');
  const selection = textArea.selectionStart;
  let value = textarea.value;
  const str = value.substring(0, textArea.selectionStart);
  const index = str.lastIndexOf('@');
  const mention = str.substring(index);
  value = `${value.substring(0, index)}${user.value}${value.substring(index + mention.length)}`;
  textarea.value = value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I skip the getting dom part, `str` refers to the value of the `textarea`, `placeholder` refers to the current intellisense, `username` refers to the real usernames and `position` is the cursor position that can be determined via `document.getElementById('textarea').selectionStart`

```js
const str = 'adfsaf @ adsfsad @ja!2123afd @eeeav @asedf';
const position = 20; // just after @ja, str[20] gives the space ' ' after @ja
const placeholder = '@ja'; // you should be able to get that dynamically.
const username = 'Jason Smith';  // you should be able to get that dynamically.

const idx = str.substring(0,position).indexOf(placeholder);
const output = `${str.substring(0,position - placeholder.length)}@${username} ${str.substring(position)}`;
console.log(output);
```